# About splitting fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, splitting-field

I understand basically what a splitting field is and how to obtain it. However, I am unable to fill in the details in the construction. To be concrete,

> Let $F$ be a field and $f(x) \in F[x]$ be monic. Write $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^k f_i(x)$ where each $f_i(x)$ is irreducible. If all the $f_i(x)$ have degree $1$ there's nothing to prove. So suppose $\deg f_1(x) > 1$. We have that $E:=F[x]/(f_1(x))$ is a field, and $r = x+(f_1(x))$ is a root of $f_1(x)$ in $E$. Also $E$ is an extension of the field $F$, so $f(x) \in E[x]$. Writing $f(x)$ as a product of irreducibles in $E[x]$, we see that $f_1(x)$ must decompose into $(x-r) g(x)$ where $g(x)$ is possibly reducible. Hence the number of irreducible factors of $f(x)$ in $E[x]$ is $>k$. So we can proceed by induction on $n-k$, where $n = \deg f(x)$.

Questions:

In what sense is $r$ a root of $f_1(x)$ in $E$? What $f_1(x)$ are we talking about? How to view the elements of $F[x]$ as elements of $E[x]$? i.e., rigorously, given $f(x) \in F[x]$, what kind of $f(x)$ are we talking about when we view $f(x)$ as an element of $E[x]$?

Comment: In the same sense that $\mathbb{C} = \mathbb{R}(i) \cong \mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)$ . In this last field $x+(x^2+1)$ is a root of $X^2+1 \in \mathbb{R}[X]$.

Comment: $f$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $F$, so by inclusion it is a polynomial with coefficients in $E$ as well. You do have to change variable name from the $x$ used to generate $E$ into something else, like $X$ or $t$.

Comment: @Arthur I see but I want to know what *exactly* does $f(x)$ look like in $E[x]$.

Comment: in $E[X] = (F[x]/(f_1(x))[X]$ you have $f(X) =  g(X)(X- x+(f_1(x))$ for some polynomial $g \in E[X]$

Comment: What is the definition of $n$? Where does this quote come from?

Comment: Sorry, I added what $n$ is (it's $\deg f(x)$). It's not quoted from anywhere. This is the proof in my textbook as I remember it. I don't have it at hand to copy the proof verbatim.

Comment: Let: $K$ be a field, $X$ an indeterminate, $f(X)\in K[X]$, $\pi:K[X]\to K[X]/f(X)$ the canonical projection. Then we get $0=\pi(f(X))=f(\pi(X))$.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard how to interpret $f(\pi(X))$? I mean surely there's no function composition here.

Comment: We have $X\in K[X]$ and $\pi:K[X]\to K[X]/(f(X))$. Thus $\pi(X)\in K[X]/(f(X))$. Moreover $f$ induces an endomap of $K[X]/(f(X))$, denoted by $f$. (This because $K[X]/(f(X))$ is a $K$-algebra, and $f\in K[X]$.)

Comment: I still don't quite understand the situation. Maybe I should get back to this later..

Comment: If $f(X)=\sum a_iX^i\in K[X]$, if $A$ is a $K$-algebra and if $b\in A$, then $f(b)=\sum a_ib^i\in A$.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your first question: You see that $E$ ist a field and so we can form the ring of polynomials over this field. Lets call it $E[T]$, just to (hopefully) minimise confusion. Now, $E$ is a extension of $F$, so we can embedd $F[x]$ into $E[T]$ by just mapping $f(x)$ to $f(T)$. Since the coefficients are in $F$ they are also in $E$, so this is well defined. If we now plug in $x \in E=F[x]/(f(x))$ into the polynomial $f(T) \in E[T]$ we get $f(x)$ back. But $f(x)$ is zero in $E$ because we modded it out. Therefore $x$ is a root in $E$ of $f$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** If $\phi:A\to B$ is a morphism of commutative rings, if $f$ is in $A[X]$, where $X$ is an indeterminate, and if $a$ is in $A$, then we have 
$$
\phi(f(a))=\phi(f)(\phi(a)).
$$